# How to use a word to index a byte array in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, indexing, arrays, cpu-word, mips

Okay, so I have a question about addressing an array in MIPS.

Let's say for example, I have something like this:

```
lw $t9,0($t5)   # $t9 is an alias for some value in memory.  Let's call it "var."
```

Suppose I want to index an array of bytes using "var":

```
la $a0,array           # Starting address of array in memory.
addi $t4,$a0,$t9       # Want to calculate address of array[var].
```

I am getting an arithmetic overflow error, and I am assuming it is because I am trying to add the value of a word to the address of the array.

---

Here is my actual code if the above does not make sense.  I am trying to convert a C function into MIPS:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)   {
    pair_table[i] = 0;
    is_closer[i] = false;
}
for (int i = 0; pairs[i]; i += 2)  {
    const char op = pairs[i];
    const char cl = pairs[i+1];
    is_closer[cl] = true;
    pair_table[op] = cl;
 }
```

Here is my MIPS translation.  I believe it is how I am differentiating between words and bytes because if I use lb instead of lw, the code will execute.  However, the output is wrong because I need the entire word rather than just a byte.  My problem is how to actually index the word value as an index for the array?

```
    la $a0,pair_table          # $a0 will hold address of pair_table.
    addi $a1,$0,256            # $a1 will hold size of tables (256) for both pair_table and is_closer.
    move $t1,$0                # Set $t1 to 0 (serves as counter for number of entries in table; can't have over 256).
    move $t2,$0                # Set $t2 to 0 (serves as counter for number of times branch to filltable has occurred).

filltable: 
    sb $0,0($a0)               # current location in table set to 0 (0 also serving as false in is_closer's case)
    addi $a0,$a0,1             # Increment current address of table by 1.
    addi $t1,$t1,1             # Increment number of entries by 1.
    slt $t3,$t1,$a1            # $t3 = (index total < 256)
    bne $t3,$0,filltable       # If (index total < 256), continue filling table.
    nop 
    bgtz $t2,setpairs         # If $t2's count is greater than 0, both pair_table and is_closer are filled.  Time to fill pairs table.
    nop

    la $a0,is_closer       # $a0 holds address of is_closer.
    move $t1,$0                # Reset $t1 to 0 (counter for number of table entries).
    addi $t2,$t2,1             # Increment filltable counter by 1.
    addi $t4,$0,1              # $t4 will hold the value 1 (true in this case).
    sb $t4,0($a0)              # Store "true" in the first entry of is_closer.
    addi $a0,$a0,1             # Go to next location in is_closer.
    addi $t1,$t1,1             # Increment number of entries by 1.
    b filltable                # Continue filling rest of is_closer table entries with 0 (false).
    nop


setpairs:   
    la $a0,pairs               # Get address of pairs table.
    move $t1,$0                # Start at index 0.
fillpairs: 
    sll $t2,$t1,2              # $t2 = current index * 4
    add $t0,$a0,$t2            # $t0 = address of pair at index
    lb $t9,0($t0)              # Get value of pairs[index].    //op//
 #  lw $t9,0($t0) ####################
    addi $t0,$t0,4             # Get next location in pairs (pairs[index+1]).  
    lb $t3,0($t0)              # Get value of pairs[index+1].  //cl//
#   lw $t3,0($t0) ####################

    la $a1,is_closer           # Get starting address of is_closer table.
    add $t6,$a1,$t3            # Get address of is_closer[cl].
    sb $t4,0($t6)              # Set is_closer[cl] to true (1).
#   sw $t4,0($t6)

    la $a2,pair_table          # Get starting address of pair_table.
    add $t5,$a2,$t9            # Get address of pair_table[op].
    sb $t3,0($t5)              # pair_table[op] = cl
#   sw $t3,0($t5) #####################

    addi $t1,$t1,2             # index += 2

    bnez $t9,fillpairs         # If pairs[i] ($t9) not yet NULL terminated, continue filling the table.
    nop

    jr $ra
    nop
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `pairs` is a 4 byte integer array, your code looks about right, if overcomplicated. One issue is that you are checking for the termination condition after the loop body, but the C version tests before the body.

As for the arithmetic overflow, you should use `addiu`/`addu` which don't generate that error. Chances are you nevertheless have a problem somewhere.

As usual, you should use a debugger/simulator to step through the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Will do.  I'll put up my solution code when I finish for if anyone ever needs a reference.  I haven't seen many array examples in MIPS where you're using an index in the way I am using them.  I'm using other variables as my indices.

Comment: Also, just an added note:  The termination condition should be fine to check after the loop body.  It essentially does the same thing.  It would look quite hideous in the code to put b fillpairs, branch back up, and THEN do a check for if pairs[i] is true.  Essentially, I am doing the exact same thing.  In fact, I think it's pretty standard in MIPS to check loop conditions at the end; then branch up if the condition is still met.  It makes no difference, and takes up less lines of code.

Comment: In general it does make a difference whether you execute the loop body even when the termination condition is already true. It might not matter in your case but it still isn't a transcript of the C code. Note that the asm code will set `is_closer[pairs[i+1]]` to true, where `i+1` is past the terminator. The C code never uses this element, it may be out of range or contain garbage.

Comment: Oh, okay, I understand what you mean.  I'll take a look at that.  Like I said, I'm going to play with the code a bit more, but I will definitely post the finished product for any other MIPS newbies.  Thanks for your comments and help!